# Concatenating a stack string with a heap string gives odd results

Tags: c++, windows, string, memory-management, tchar

I am sure the following has a rational explanation but I am nevertheless a bit baffled.

The issue is with a function which creates a `_TCHAR[CONSTANT]`, a `_TCHAR*`, concatenates them and returns the result.

For some reason the call to `whatTheHeck()` from `_tmain()` returns gibberish.

```
_TCHAR* whatTheHeck(_TCHAR* name) {
    _TCHAR Buffer[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRet;
    dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, Buffer);
    _TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
    what = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\"));
    what = _tcscat(what, name);
    return what;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    _TCHAR* failure = whatTheHeck(TEXT("gibberish);")); // not again ..
    _tprintf(TEXT("|--> %s\n"), failure);

    _TCHAR* success = createFileName(TEXT("readme.txt")); // much better
    _tprintf(TEXT("|--> %s\n"), success);

    return 0;
}
```

In contrast, when going with heap things work as expected.

```
_TCHAR* createFileName(_TCHAR* name) {
    _TCHAR* Buffer = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRet;
    dwRet = GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, Buffer);
    Buffer = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\"));
    Buffer = _tcscat(Buffer, name);
    return Buffer;
}
```

**Why the difference?**

Is it because `_tcscat()` concatenates memory addresses instead of their contents and return purges the stack?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are lots of problems with your code. Let's take it apart, shall we:

```
_TCHAR* whatTheHeck(_TCHAR* name)   // We're inside a local scope
{
    _TCHAR Buffer[BUFSIZE];         // "Buffer" has automatic storage

    _TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];  // "what" points to newly allocated dyn. memory

    what = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\"));  // Oh no, we overwrite "what" - leak!
                                         // Now what == Buffer.

    what = _tcscat(what, name);  // Equivalent to "_tcscat(Buffer, name)"

    return Buffer;               // WTPF? We're returning a local automatic!
 }
```

As you can see, you are both causing a memory leak with a gratuitious and reckless `new`, and you are also returning the address of a local object past its lifetime!

I would strongly recommmend

1. reading the [documentation for `strcat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282.aspx) and understanding "source" and "destination",
2. not using `strcat`, but a safer version like `strncat`,
3. not using `strncat`, but instead `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

That happens because `_tcscat` concatenates *into* the destination parameter, which is the first one, and then returns it. So, it returns a pointer to the array `Buffer` and it gets stored in `what` in this line:

```
what = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\"));
```

Then this pointer is returned, and you have undefined behavior once you try to use it, because the local `Buffer` no longer exists.

Furthermore, the line above also causes the memory allocated for `what` to be leaked:

```
_TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
what = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\")); // this loses the memory allocated
                                    // in the previous line
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamically allocated memory `what` points to is not initialized. It contains gibberish. `_tcscat` expects the string to be properly null-terminated.

```
_TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE]();
```

This fills `what` with `'\0'` characters.

```
_TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
what[0] = '\0';
```

This properly terminates the empty string.

`GetCurrentDirectory` doesn't expect the buffer to be null-terminated. It writes something to that and properly null-terminates it. You can then pass that to concatenation functions.

---

As a side note, your function seems to be vulnerable to buffer overflows. Apparently you allow `GetCurrentDirectory` to fill up everything you allocated, and then you want to append to it without caring if there is any more space left.

Comment: The allocated memory `what` points to is leaked and not the cause of the gibberish.

Comment: I assumed `_tcscat` works like `strcat` in which case assignments of the result should be ok, though redundant (the destination pointer is not modified anyway).

Comment: @Martinho: I missed that OP's passing `Buffer` the first time. Can't imagine someone managing C strings without any idea how the C string functions work...

Answer (score 0):

```
_TCHAR* what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
what = _tcscat(Buffer, TEXT("\\"));
```

Aren't you overwriting `what` with the `Buffer` which is a local variable to the function. Once the stack is unwound, `Buffer` goes out of scope and thus you get unexpected values. Also it's a memory leak.

In heap allocation scenarios, you may prefer to declare the pointer a `const` to avoid such hazards:

```
_TCHAR* const what = new _TCHAR[BUFSIZE];
        ^^^^^ (avoids overwriting)
```

The better approach is to use `std::string` and be out of such small issues.